# What does "uberbond" mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, nouns, idiom-meaning

I am reading the following article:

> Nelson, T., Maxfield, S., & Kolb, D. (2009). Women entrepreneurs and
>   venture capital: Managing the shadow negotiation. International
>   Journal of Gender and Entrepreneurship, 1(1), 57–76.
>   https://doi.org/10.1108/17566260910942345

One of the persons interviewed in the article said

> For Jenny: (Among men with a certain, shared background), There is a
>   certain uberbond.

What does "uberbond" mean? I searched on Oxford English Dictionary, Oxford Advanced Learners Dictionary, Merriam-Webster dictionary with no avail

Comment: Probably not a real word, but [uber](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/uber) "is used before nouns to mean "extreme" or "extremely good or successful":

Comment: You see the word 'uberbond' used in science-fiction scenarios involving telepathy, mind-contact, etc, for  [example](https://www.martha.net/2007/12/this-is-why-i-dont-write-on-my-lunch-breaks/) "the ‘uberbond’ that Akela’s looking for will be more of a telepathic hivemind entity"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*uberbond* may not actually exist outside of Sci-Fi, but...

***uber*** can be...

> ...used before nouns to mean "extreme" or "extremely good or successful":

-[Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/uber)

although it might be better hyphenated as uber-bond. It is a loanword from German, and first usage in English possibly dates back to *ubermensch* as described by Nietzche in *Thus spake Zarusthra* (1883).

In your case, I would interpret *uberbond* to be a kind of 'male bonding' situation, or a "us and them" mentality as seen in Boy Scouts, the military, fraternities, social lodges such as the Moose, or even the Masons.

Comment: @Rattler - "ubermensch as described by Nietzche in Thus spake Zarusthra (1883)." The term got popular in certain quarters a few decades later.

Comment: What, I shudder to imagine, is an unterbond?